# Откуда берутся cookie в данном запросе?

Tags: javascript, html

Заранее скажу, что в работе JS и HTML не разбираюсь на 100% - сам питонист. Вопрос вот в чем. Хотел узнать как работает авторизация на одном сайте. Полностью загрузил главную страницу сайта. Включил девтул. Нажимаю на элемент **Login/Register**, который присутствует на странице. Элемент запускает js, который создает iframe элемент-окно с помощью Popup. Через манипуляции кода создается URL(URL кросс-доменный). И, **после этих строк**, запрос появляется во вкладке Сеть в девтуле:

```js
window.setTimeout(function() {
            this.__loadTime = (new Date).getTime();
            if (n) {
                if ("is_IPV6_Message" === t)
                    if (e != -1 && 1 != e && "{URSOPENBGPVALUE}" === window.URSOPENBGP)
                        this._url_cache = b(this._url_cache);
                n.src = this._url_cache
            }
```

n - это iframe элемент страницы.
1й вопрос: Правильно ли я понимаю, что строка n.src = this._url_cache добавляют в тэг ifram атрибут src и его url-ссылку, после этого браузер сделал запрос, так как это src элемента?
2й вопрос: Это первый запрос на кросс домен. В заголовках запроса есть куки. Откуда они могут взяться? Я посмотрел все исходники, посмотрел все шаги от нажатия на элемент логин, до запроса url, посмотрел все предыдущие ответные заголовки. Нигде нет данных кук. Может это какие-то куки, добавляемые самим браузером? Такое бывает? Вот сами куксы:

```
Cookie: __snaker__id=UKyAWjfXaJSnrcDH; utid=WsuSMGsXZu9wtepNAO7gZh7NqZGJHdUj; NTES_WEB_FP=6846d65544dcbfb8de76ce41fd804ed1; _9755xjdesxxd_=32; l_yd_s_netease_buffmUWknxk=715994DB6318C68DA689CA2117BAE8D6E1139BF8CBA07EDDA7AEF9B6F09F32AEEAC4ED2DDE48F97F7741D083E898C12627E87DF22FB85AACA6796372EA50D49EE9FC5187C73EB7C0093CDA8B9F374954F595BCDC479EE92DD6C4F8C1248566876A4A6453F9ABBC192325FB7A1C9369B7; YD00000710348764%3AWM_NI=GY8ZAlOe9AZk%2FUbhKC2hYD3COFe6hi6ZCI%2Fo8LJBx6WJ4GZ%2FUGUIO3DUFjPzXGPiM8FhKj%2FFzvoJ6oxIdPlwlmQqTRVVSAPaozYCrMSH%2BfpV1rH5fYEj9iNxH%2B9KCjZsYVk%3D; YD00000710348764%3AWM_NIKE=9ca17ae2e6ffcda170e2e6eeb2ee3bfb8a00d7ef6191b88fb7c54b979a9a82d8698599ff88e66bb4b081d5e22af0fea7c3b92a8587f8bbc4688dbbf7a2d961ed8bae89ca49f2b897a5b2498d9aabd7eb63f6868daaae65fc9486a3fb3e9596fca8d92597999baace39888b8a8bd3729c99a08ad03486b8858bae4ebaaaa1abb565bc97acb1ef7db0b39f92d75a968a9da2d36bada697a4f1479198e587f35ef3ae88d6e55387b6f78acd748cf5f7acc2629aad97b7ea37e2a3; YD00000710348764%3AWM_TID=maQsa%2Fyv1blFRFABEBaECEpwgA4IPo%2FE; gdxidpyhxdE=XUxPGygsMNevoRwzXOvhZMS3qTBIsbZvw5YZdOD8dgM284t%2F1Aauqmx%5C%2B2Xap6C%2Bc1yCsxi%2BjXUoYwJDh6TDdcsK7sdD8pX9YITbWtTyWCp%2Fv6E5%5C2yU0hsir2kQA5SpnRGGO%2BLA5%2F%5CmLr2782%5CJ7u6eLGX7gYdHgCf%2F6hR8%2FJ9Nf7Ue%3A1667733679411
```

Comment: P.S. Да. Забыл в setTimeout передать 2й аргумент и закрыть скобку. Но суть это не меняет

Comment: 1) Да в атрибут `src` указывается ссылка на которую браузер делает запрос. 2) На самом сайте могут выдаваться эти куки (Для примера в этой функции `b(this._url_cache)`, не совсем уверен, но вы других исходников не предоставили).

Comment: Это похоже на какие-то защитные соли, что б контент который предназначался для определенного домена по url, мамкины хацкеры не тырили.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 в ответ приходит html с css и скриптами в теле. Его можно и без кук получить. Просто я хочу понять откуда они там появляются. Я все пересмотрел и ничего не нашел связанного с этими куками. Ни в html, ни в скриптах, ни в заголовках.

Comment: Поще будет если в вопросе ссылку на сайт дадите. Сложно гадать, что там может быть если не видеть код.